# How to move an object over a deformed surface and make in follow the surface?

Tags: modeling, animation

So I modelled this boat and a lake using ocean modifier.

[image]

As you can see when it moves, it intersects with the water. Sometimes it's under water and sometimes over it.

Anyone knows how to make it move over the surface such that it adjusts itself on Z axis and only a part of it is underwater at  all times(Like real boats).

Apart from keyframing it to move properly, I have tried everything

Any help is greatly appreciated

Thanks in advance

**Blend File:** https://pasteall.org/blend/963dfcbdfd6b468a9f2712981165494d

Comment: tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lxLKpweEkD0&list=PLvE1XtiXcfOklbybsDhi44eEG72cCzc4v&index=6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a plane with enough subdivisions, and give it a shrinkwrap modifier with target ocean. Add a vertex group with all vertices to the plane.
Then use copylocation constraint on z-axis to your boat and the vertex group. Hide your plane.

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: @vklidu: I extended the answer

Comment: Thanks @vklidu. I changed it again. I should have watched my own video more often…‍♂️

Comment: It's your own? That makes this thing very fun :) Cheers BTW Thanks I didnt know vert-group under Constraint ... until now I used 3point vertex parent thing ... time to check new way how good it is ... probably time to change old habits :)

Comment: My memory is very…Ähm…let‘s call it „forgettable“ sometimes I don‘t know what I did yesterday…even if I do these tutorials - and some I made for the 10th time…I forgot thembut the good thing is: everything is new every day…just kidding 