# Objects intersecting in render but not in viewport

Tags: modeling, rendering, animation, cycles-render-engine, constraints

So I modelled this boat and made it move across the lake using a shrinkwrap modifier and copylocation constraint(Like Chris said in this [question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/223282/how-to-move-an-object-over-a-deformed-surface-and-make-in-follow-the-surface?noredirect=1#comment377496_223282) )

Now the problem is that whenever I view this boat in viewport, there is no intersection between water and boat but whenever render the scene, the boat and water interects.

**Viewport:**
[image]

**Render:** [image]

Anyone have an idea why this is happening and how to solve it? I am at the end of my wits here.

**BLEND FILE:** https://pasteall.org/blend/16806ed8d94b4412b3db3799957febc5

Answer (score 0):

it depends on your frame.

With starting frame 5 i see water in your boat in viewport...

[image]

[image]

it looks like you applied the boolean modifier. I wouldn't have done that.

And if you apply, you cannot change it afterwards.

And i think - if you apply, it is "just for the moment". But unapplied the boolean modifier will also work for animated objects.

Comment: I didn't use boolean at all.

Comment: Also, in frame 5 did water appear in both viewport and render? When I render frame 1 water is not visible in viewport but is visible in render

Comment: Ok, I thought you used a Boolean. My mistake. The solution with the shrinkwrap just moves the boat with the ocean. It does not (!) prevent water „flowing“ in the boat. This you have to do with a Boolean modifier.